# Should we remove the [french] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

It seems to me the [french](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/french) tag doesn't add much to Stack Overflow. It has no description and is a mess.

The questions fall mainly under the following categories:

- They use the French version of an OS/program (like Windows). It is safe to say that there are not enough errors specific to a French version to warrant a tag.
- Their problem is related to French accentuation. In that case there are better tags for the job.
- Their problem is related to translation. In that case [translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translation) is a better tag.
- People wanting an explanation in French because they don't understand English. <s>If there are enough of these people, maybe we could have a "Stack Overflow en français" site.</s> (Already rejected, see [this answer by Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370387/5211833))
- There are currently 142 questions with the [french](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/french) tag.

Comment: hmmmm....  there are specific French characters that can cause its own truckload of errors with the wrong encoding... but it doesn't warrant a tag, imho.

Comment: Je ne sais pas.

Comment: @Patrice, I agree, there are tags for that. I'll add that to the question though

Comment: *Their problem is related to French accentuation. In that case there are better tags for the job.* Can anyone elaborate about these tags? Would [`[character-encoding]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) be a suitable replacement? Because there are only 59 questions tagged `[french]`, so we can make quick work of it if we know what to do. And by the way, let's bury the [`[latin]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latin) tag too, it exhibits the same problem.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a burninate request. But it's not tagged [burninate-request]. It probably should be.

Comment: Okay, I added that tag

Comment: Fry the [french].

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi not necessarily a 1:1 replacement, but near. Just check context.

Comment: _"Pardon my [[tag:french]]"_

Comment: "French accentuation" isn't necessarily always French. Other languages utilise é or ç. Slavic languages use accents on s and v etc. etc. Nothing to do specifically with French.

Comment: [Voilà](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voil%C3%A0#Interjection)! (Yes, the spelling in English. Or a spelling.)

Answer (score 9):

There's a slight problem that we need to solve: The question *[Why can't my program compile under Windows 7 in French?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22780466/792066)*

It's locked and if you read it, it is less of a C++ question as it's a fun/joke question. I don't feel like it has any "historical" significance; it was asked when the "fun" questions were already recognized as a problem, avoided like a plague, and even then the *french* [tag wasn't considered a good tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22780466/revisions) (in fact, it was readded more for "fun"). I don't feel that that question has any lasting value.

Comment: I agree it's an April Fools prank that should at least have the `[french]` tag removed from it. Light will understand (probably).

Comment: It can safely be retagged to `[français]` or perhaps `[Ç++] `.

Answer (score 6):

There should not be, in my opinion, a tag for each language. Why? Because general language questions are off-topic. The tag is mainly used for questions about doing something in French, for example print a French character, and questions related to French characters or strings in general.

The tag is unneeded there. No one can be an expert in these questions tagged [french](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/french) because the language each time would be different and simply no one can be an expert in all languages.

Finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22780466) historically-locked question is not a problem. It can either be deleted (it does not seem a good question to me) or have a moderator remove the  tag, since in every burn at least one moderator is involved.

So, let's burninate it.