# Create French Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, languages

Stack Overflow has some different languages like [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com). I think it will be a great idea to add a French Stack Overflow: `fr.stackoverflow.com`.

### Why?

First of all, not all French developer speak English, so when they come on Stack Overflow thanks to Google, they might understand nothing and they try to ask some questions which are very badly formulated. So with a French Stack Overflow, they will be able to post questions in their mother language.

Also, Stack Overflow will get a lot of users if they add a French site.

Finally, it will be a great idea to add a way to translate questions. Like this the "big" questions will be available in different languages.

Comment: Didn't they say they aren't looking at expanding to other languages for a bit now?

Comment: I thought this had been proposed on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) but I can't find it right now. I know it has been discussed and turned down before.

Comment: See https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition

Comment: @ChrisF [I proposed one once](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106477/stack-overflow-in-french), but it got closed and deleted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be an Area 51 proposal rather than a Meta post.

Comment: The question happened also on the Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299682/259412 . There are various answers, you are free to choose your own, independently from their scores...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There isn't a `fr.stackoverflow.com` because Stack Overflow has done their research on what foreign-language developer communities exist and have ranked them by various criteria, and French hasn't come out on top. Setting up such a language site is *a lot of work*, and Stack Overflow has limited resources.

See [*Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition*](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition):

> In the 'hopper' we've got a few more languages that seem like good candidates for localization from a technical standpoint. Turkish, German & Korean stand at the front. Since each new site is an *enormous* undertaking, our goal with each one is to reach the largest group of developers we're currently not serving as well as we should.
>
> Deciding on the next language is not purely about how many people speak a language. It's more about how many *developers* speak a language, and aren't likely to be very proficient in English. There are also many technical, and sometimes political complications that we have to consider.
>
> We're looking at years worth of data that we have in order to determine where the next largest net-win for developer inclusion might be.

So what languages to support is based on the number of developers in a language not proficient in English, and a few other factors.

But, there aren't that many resources to drive the creation of more such sites:

> After Spanish, it's going to be a bit of time before we're ready to take on another language. I can't say precisely *how* long other than much longer than I'm comfortable asking people to wait, while the Area 51 process itself continues to raise people's expectations.
>
> What's important for everyone that has proposed Stack Overflow in another language is that *we've heard you, and we know there's interest.* If you propose something and it's closed, it's *not* us saying no. It's simply us saying not yet, and probably *not for a while, but we're working on it*.

Finally, to address your last point:

> Finally, it will be a great idea to add a way to translate questions. Like this the "big" questions will be available in different languages.

No, there won't be such a 'translation' service. Each site is a new community, with different expectations and their own culture. If similar questions arise there, then that'll be within that local culture and community, and with new insights and solutions having a chance to stand out better. That's how it should be!